# Linear algebra: sources for most basic proofs.

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

I am taking linear algebra courses in this semester. I wanted to start my study but I stuck with these basic proofs:

e.g.

- Determinant of block diagonal matrix $\det \operatorname{diag} (A,B)$ is $(\det A)×(\det B)$
- Interchanged two row changes sign of the determinant.
- The same two row means determinant is zero(it follows from above one)
- Understanding the definition nxn matrices' determinants.
- etc...

I assumed that I can clear all the proofs like these but these theorems somehow are consisted in each other. Therefore, I want to  study all of them in a logical sequence. Can one advise me some kind of book/source ? I searched some but they did not satisfy me.

Comment: If there are $m$ definitions of the deteminant, there are $m$ different proofs of each of the facts you mentioned. What's your definition of determinant?

Comment: There are many on line texts for linear algebra. ( https://www.google.com/search?q=linear+algebra+text ) . Find one that suits your style and read about determinants.